# Weird Functional Equation problem on the irrationals

Tags: functional-equations

This weird question was given by my professor as a part of my assignment :

$\textbf{Question :}$

“Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that it satisfies $f(x + y) = x f(\frac{1}{y}) + y f(\frac{1}{x})$, whenever $x$ and $y$ are both irrational numbers. Then prove that $f(0)$ is always $0$.”

$\textbf{My attempt :}$

Since $0$ is rational, we can’t let any of the variables to be $0$. So I tried the substitution $y = -x$ to get $f(0) = x f(\frac{1}{-x}) - x f(\frac{1}{x})$.

I tried proving f to be an even function after this, so that $f(0)$ becomes $0$. But I couldn’t do so or proceed further anyhow.

Can somebody kindly provide me hints or solutions for this problem ?

Comment: What is $.$ here?

Comment: Hint: Take the equations for $x = y = t$ and $x= y = 1/(2t)$.  What can you conclude?

Comment: . is the simple product of real numbers. I shall edit it once

Comment: "(0) is always 0" is not understandable.

Comment: @user It could be better phrased but it is easily understandable: "for every such function $f$, $f(0)=0$".

Comment: @RobertIsrael Shouldn't your comment be an answer?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, After considering your hints, I got $2t^2 = 1$. Is that what you meant ? So I let $y = -x$ and $x = \frac{1}{√2}$ to solve this. Thank you for your help !

Comment: @VinayKarthik Can you post that as a full solution, or edit it into your answer?

Comment: @AnneBauval I did not see this possibility. This means it was not easily understandable.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Is the conclusion that the function is identically $0$ correct?

Comment: @VinayKarthik No, what you get is not $2t^2=1$.

Comment: @CalvinLin , Here is my solution. Let $x = y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, in the original equation. After simple algebra, we get $f(\sqrt{2}) = 0$. Similarly $f(-\sqrt{2}) = 0$.  Now let $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y = -x$ to conclude.

Comment: @user, Even I had the same hunch as yours. So should I ask the question of whether f is identically 0 as a new question or edit the current question ? Any suggestions ? I am new member, so I am quite unsure.

Comment: This is a complicated question. If you are sure that you found the correct answer you can publish it. Doing this I would thank @RobertIsrael for the hint. If you are unsure you can edit the question, give the alleged solution and ask if it is correct.

Comment: @VinayKarthik Great. Instead of leaving it as a comment, can you post it as an answer (down below), or edit it into your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $x = y = t$ (any irrational) you get
$$ f(2t) = 2 t f(1/t) $$
and with $x = y = 1/(2t)$ you get
$$f(1/t) = f(2t)/t$$
Substitute the first into the second and it says
$$ f(1/t) = 2 f(1/t)$$
from which you conclude $f(1/t) = 0$, i.e. $f$ is $0$ on all irrationals.
Then use $y = -x$ to get $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: It can be proved that $f(x)=0$ for any rational number as well.

Comment: Yes of course: if $r$ is rational, take any irrational $x$ and $y = r - x$

Comment: Excellent @RobertIsrael ! I didn't think of a substitution. I simply equated the arguments of f in the first equation of your solution to get $2t^2 = 1$. From there my solution follows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, after taking suggestions from @RobertIsrael in the comments.

Let $x = y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, in the original equation. After simple algebra, we get $f(\sqrt{2}) = 0$. Similarly we get $f(-\sqrt{2}) = 0$ by taking $x = y = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$ . Now let $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $y = −x$ to conclude.

Comment: It would be correct to explain the "simple algebra" here and not in the comment to the previous answer.